# How to store image outside of the website's root directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

**I want all images uploaded by users to be saved outside of my website directory.**

Let me explain you all

---

Suppose i have a website deployed in a server and directory path is:

e.g. `D:\TestWeb\`

here currently some other directory i have added to store images as:

```
 D:\TestWeb\imgProfile

 D:\TestWeb\imgLocation

 D:\TestWeb\Scan
```

**but i don't want to store these inside of my root directory D:\TestWeb\
I want to store these into some other location as**

```
 E:\img\imgProfile

 E:\img\imgLocation

 E:\img\Scan
```

here i am not able to access this  `E:\img\imgProfile` using http.

**Please suggest any logic.**

Comment: How are you hosting your website? IIS or other method? If IIS, what version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the path in the web.config file

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="DocumentationLocation" value="E:\img\imgProfile" />
</appSettings>
```

In the code:

```
string savePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DocumentationLocation"];

string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(savePath + filename);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a virtual directory in IIS, e.g. `/Images` that will point to `D:\TestWeb\imgLocation`. Then you just use [MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to get the physical path to your image folder by using the virtual path `/Images`.

Comment: But he want to save into a folder which in not a part of virtual folder.

Comment: @Shekhar what you probably want is to create three virtual directories (`imgProfile`, `imgLocation` and `Scan`) under the root of your website. These directories will simply point to the ones on your E:\ drive and you'll use `MapPath` to resolve virtual path (e.g. `/imgProfile`) to a physical path (on the E:\ drive). Makes sense?

Comment: @CollectMeNow it does, I use this method all the time.